# longest common substring python

Tags: python-3.x, string, substring

Given a list of k (k≤100) strings of length at most 1000, find a longest common substring of all strings in the given list.

This is based on a problem from Rosalind.

---

### Exact Problem Statement:

A common substring of a collection of strings is a substring of every member of the collection. We say that a common substring is a longest common substring if there does not exist a longer common substring. For example, "CG" is a common substring of "ACGTACGT" and "AACCGTATA", but it is not as long as possible; in this case, "CGTA" is a longest common substring of "ACGTACGT" and "AACCGTATA".

Note that the longest common substring is not necessarily unique; for a simple example, "AA" and "CC" are both longest common substrings of "AACC" and "CCAA".

Given: A collection of k (k≤100) DNA strings of length at most 1 kbp each in FASTA format.

Return: A longest common substring of the collection. (If multiple solutions exist, you may return any single solution.) 
http://rosalind.info/problems/lcsm/

---

I tried writing a straight forward program to do this. I thought that I had done it correctly as it worked on all the example cases I threw at it, but Rosalind says my output is incorrect. I have thought about it for a couple days now and I think I'm tired. I would appreciate a second pair of eyes to help spot my mistake.

```
def get_lcs(string_list):
    string0 = string_list[0]
    n0 = len(string0)
    lcs = ''
    not_common_substrings = set()
    #pick a starting/ending index of the first string to
    #pick a potential common substring
    for i in range(n0):
        if len(lcs) > len(string0[i:]):
            break
        substring = ''
        substring_in = True
        for j in range(i, n0):
            if substring_in == False:
                break
            substring = string0[i:j+1]
            if substring in not_common_substrings:
                break

            #go through all the rest of the strings
            #in the list and see if our substring is a
            #common substring. If it is, and is longer than
            #the current longest common substring,
            #replace the current lcs with our substring
            if len(substring) < len(lcs):
                continue
            for string in string_list[1:]:
                if substring not in string:
 #optional          print(f'i={i}, j={j}, substring={substring} not in string={string}, lcs={lcs}\n')
                    not_common_substrings.add(substring)
                    substring_in = False
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            if substring_in == True:
                if len(substring) > len(lcs):
                    lcs = substring

    return lcs
```

I include a comment that I used to see if a substring was not in a string in the list, then print out where the substring is and what string it does not belong to.

I tried with various examples, here is a list of strings from rosalind: [clipboard with list of strings](https://cl1p.net/rosalind)

My program returned the longest common substring `'A'`, but this is incorrect.

When I uncomment the print statement in the code, I get

```
i=0, j=1, substring=AC not in string=TATCGGAAGTCGTAATGGTATAAGTTCGTTATCGAAGGCC, lcs=A

i=1, j=2, substring=CG not in string=GTTATGATGAACACATTTTATTAGCAGGTTGATCTGGTGG, lcs=A

i=2, j=3, substring=GC not in string=CTAATATCGGGAGATGTCATTTACAACTATATCTCACTGT, lcs=A

i=3, j=4, substring=CT not in string=TTGATCAAAGTATTTTCAAGAATGCGGCGGTTAAGTAGCGGGGGGTCCAACGGGTATTCG, lcs=A

i=4, j=5, substring=TC not in string=CTGGGGCGCACCCAGCTGAATTACTAAATAGATAATTACTACTTGGGGCCCGTTGTTACG, lcs=A

i=6, j=7, substring=TG not in string=GCAGATCCCGTCTAGGCGGGAAATCGGTAAGCCCTCCCTCTTTTCCAAACCCGAGGCATC, lcs=A

i=7, j=8, substring=GG not in string=TGAGCTGCCCTCAGAGAATCTGAAGTAGCGTGCTGAGTCTCGCACTGTGTAGCGAGTCAG, lcs=A

i=14, j=15, substring=GT not in string=CCTACTTCGAAGACCCTTCCCGACGCTGGCGGATAAATGCGACGGGGAGAACCTCTCTAT, lcs=A

i=15, j=16, substring=TA not in string=TGTCTGTCGCAGATTGCTTGGTGCCCTGGGCCGCAACATTCGACAGCGCGCATGAGGCAT, lcs=A

i=16, j=17, substring=AA not in string=GACCGTATATGCATTTAGACGATTCTTCGGAGACGGACTTATTAGACGACTTCCATTTTG, lcs=A

i=17, j=18, substring=AT not in string=AGCTCCCTCCTCGTCTTGTTTGAACGTAAGTCAGGTCGCAAAACCTTTAAAGGTCTCCAG, lcs=A

i=18, j=19, substring=TT not in string=TGAGCTGCCCTCAGAGAATCTGAAGTAGCGTGCTGAGTCTCGCACTGTGTAGCGAGTCAG, lcs=A

i=21, j=22, substring=AG not in string=TACTGAATATCGCTCGTCGGGCACGCTACCTATATGCTGTTATCACGTTGAACGAAATTT, lcs=A

i=24, j=25, substring=CA not in string=CCTACTTCGAAGACCCTTCCCGACGCTGGCGGATAAATGCGACGGGGAGAACCTCTCTAT, lcs=A

i=36, j=37, substring=GA not in string=TCAAACCATGTACTATCTCCTTAGCCTGTGCCAAAGTCCCCCTTAAGCCGCTCATGGTGG, lcs=A

i=40, j=41, substring=CC not in string=CTAATATCGGGAGATGTCATTTACAACTATATCTCACTGT, lcs=A
```

Which seems to be true...

Comment: Do you know what they want instead?  The one-letter strings 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T' are all possible answers.  Or please give a link to the exact wording of the problem statement.

Comment: http://rosalind.info/problems/lcsm/         As far as I could tell, they are fine with any longest common substring, but unfortunately, I do not know the correct answer. Thank you for taking a look

Comment: Thanks!  Next thing to clear up: the problem statement you linked to in your comment states that  there will be no more than 100 strings in the input.  But the list of strings you linked to in your question contains 1700 strings (1623 of which are unique).  So are you absolutely sure the list of strings you linked to is relevant?  It's far longer than the problem statement says can exist.  My own code to find all the longest common substrings finds only "A', 'C', 'G', and 'T" for that list.

Comment: Because of your observation, I now know what I did wrong. I definitely incorrectly read the file in. Thanks for your time.